# Parameters from RESTRequest in Client are not passed to Server - Delphi

Tags: delphi

Me Parameters from RESTRequest are not being passed from client to server, when I check the parameters in the server side they are all empty.

```
  // Configurando REST Client
  ...
  RESTClient1.Accept := 'application/json, text/plain; q=0.9, text/html;q=0.8,';
  RESTClient1.AcceptCharset := 'UTF-8, *;q=0.8';
  RESTClient1.BaseURL := Format('http://%s:%s/datasnap/rest', [IPV4, '8080']);
  RESTClient1.ContentType := 'image/jpeg';
  RESTClient1.HandleRedirects := True;
  RESTClient1.RaiseExceptionOn500 := False;
  RESTRequest1.Client := RESTClient1;

  RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('AArquivo', 'fotosoon', pkGETorPOST, [poDoNotEncode], ctTEXT_PLAIN);
  RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('Pasta', 'teste', pkGETorPOST, [poDoNotEncode], ctTEXT_PLAIN);
  RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('Size', StrSize.ToString, pkGETorPOST, [poDoNotEncode], ctTEXT_PLAIN);
  RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('ASetStream', fStream, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkREQUESTBODY,
    [poDoNotEncode],
    ctIMAGE_JPEG);

  RESTRequest1.Resource := 'TServerMethods1/UploadFile';
  RESTRequest1.Response := RESTResponse1;
  RESTRequest1.SynchronizedEvents := False;
  RESTRequest1.Execute;
```

I tried to send the parameters in other ways, including:

```
RESTRequest1.AddParameter('AArquivo', 'filename');
```

All four parameters are null in the server side, the only way I could successfully pass the parameters it was by putting it in the url.

```
RESTClient1.BaseURL := Format('http://%s:%s/datasnap/rest', [IPV4, '8080']);
RESTClient1.BaseURL := RESTClient1.BaseURL + '/TServerMethods1/UploadFile';
RESTClient1.BaseURL := RESTClient1.BaseURL + '/fotosoon/teste/' + StrSize.ToString;
```

By this way the three parameters values arrive correctly at the server side, however, It is missing the `fStream: TStream` parameter, which can not be passed in the url.